# Calling model method and passing params Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Graphql mutation to save a `User` that looks kinda like this:

```
class CreateUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
    argument :email, String, required: true
    argument :password, String, required: true
    argument :password_confirmation, String, required: true
    argument :first_name, String, required: false
    argument :last_name, String, required: false
    argument :middle_name, String, required: false
    argument :source, String, required: false

    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true
    field :token, String, null: true

    def resolve(args)
          user = User.new(password: args[:password], password_confirmation: args[:password_confirmation], email: args[:email])
    
          profile = user.build_profile
          profile.first_name = args[:first_name] if args[:first_name].present?
          profile.last_name = args[:last_name] if args[:last_name].present?
          profile.middle_name = args[:middle_name] if args[:middle_name].present?
          user.save!
    
          UserMailer.with(user: user).send_initial_password_instructions.deliver_now if args[:source].present?
    
          # current_user needs to be set so authenticationToken can be returned
          context[:current_user] = user
    
          MutationResult.call(obj: { user: user, token: user.authentication_token }, success: user.persisted?, errors: user.errors.full_messages)
     end
end
```

All good here. BUT... I have a model named `Contact`. Which is quite empty:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs to :user, optional: true
end
```

So what I am trying to do is to have a method created on `Contact` that whenever I create a `User` I can send some `args` to `Contact` and let the `Contact` method execute the `save!`

#### This is what I've been trying: Contact.rb

```
def self.create_with_user(args)
    contact = Contact.new(args)
    contact.user = User.new(email: args[:email], password: args[:password], password_confirmation: args[:password_confirmation])
    contact.user.save!
  end
```

#### This is what I've been trying: create_user.rb (graphql mutation)

```
def resolve(args)
          user = User.new(password: args[:password], password_confirmation: args[:password_confirmation], email: args[:email])

          profile = user.build_profile
          profile.first_name = args[:first_name] if args[:first_name].present?
          profile.last_name = args[:last_name] if args[:last_name].present?
          profile.middle_name = args[:middle_name] if args[:middle_name].present?

          contact = Contact.create_with_user(args)
          user.contact = contact

          user.save!

          UserMailer.with(user: user).send_initial_password_instructions.deliver_now if args[:source].present?
          

          # current_user needs to be set so authenticationToken can be returned
          context[:current_user] = user

          MutationResult.call(obj: { user: user, token: user.authentication_token }, success: user.persisted?, errors: user.errors.full_messages)
     end
```

But this results into a `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'to' for Contact:Class`.
Newbie rails here so I am really interested in learning this. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was generated from `contact.rb` you have a type its `belongs_to` but you have `belongs to`.

`contact.rb`

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs to :user, optional: true
end
```

**Preferred Solutions**

If the creation of the Contact should always happen and you don't have any custom params from the endpoint, use a callback on the User model.

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_contact

  private

  def create_contact
    Contact.create(user: self, .....) # the other params you need to pass from model
  end
end
```

If you have custom params from the endpoint you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and make the contact params nested on the user.

```
params = {
  user: {
    user_params,
    contact: {
      contact_params
    }
  }
}
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end
```

Comment: Hello!! Thanks for the response friend!!! 
I don't have nested parameters, which makes it easier for me. But, with the callback, there is no need to call a method from a model to the Mutation? Callbacks looks more easier.

Comment: Whenever I get to the callback method. I get this issue:

   `def create_contact
     byebug
     Contact.create!(user: self, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email)
   end`

`*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'to' for Contact:Class` 
Does this mean my user-contact relationship us quite wrong?

Comment: @theKid It seems that you have an error on the `Contact.rb` file.

Comment: This is the only thing I have on my `Contact.rb` file:

`class Contact < ApplicationRecord

  belongs to :user, optional: true
end`

Comment: @theKid Do you have a line where the error occurs? Something is wrong and you need to debug it.

Comment: Yes, it occurs exactly when it goes through here:

`Contact.create!(user: self, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email)`

My theory is that my User and Contact relationship is quite wrong???

Comment: Is that error could be related to some association issue? I am honestly not quite sure. :(

Comment: @theKid You have a `has_one :contact` on the `User.rb`?

Comment: Yes, `has_one :contact, dependent: :destroy` and for some reason it markes that error. Now. I just found out using `user.contact` makes that error. And I also used 
`user.methods.sort`, `contact` does not appear as a method for contact. So wierd.

Comment: @theKid You have the wrong syntax on your `cotanct.rb` file. It's `belongs_to` not `belongs to`.

Comment: OMG!!!! you were right! This got solved. I feel dumb :(